# import excel data into database with formatting using mvc4

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to store excel data into database with all formatting.

For an example, Excel cell contains:

```
<p>I <b>love</b> <i>Stack</i> over flow</p>
```

I have tried to many things to do this, but I couldn't get the proper way.

So please help me

Comment: Databases store plain text. How do you want to encode the formatting? HTML perhaps?

Comment: yes, i want to store with html tags into database. but how to publish excel in .htm using mvc4. and then store it in datatable. i published manually but there are many classes in .htm file.

Answer (score 0):

There are no types that allow you to save a text fields with editing. You can convert it into html and store it into a varchar or XML column or you can store the entire spreadsheet into a varbinary type column.

Comment: is there any .dll or component which can easily store excel data in datatable with formatting?

Comment: No - sorry I don't know of any package that does this.